# Ruby: Logic of regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex, conditional-statements

```
Player = Struct.new(:reference, :name, :state, :items, :location)

# Setting game initials
game_condition = 0
player = Player.new(:player, "Amr Koritem", :alive, [:knife, :gun])
puts player.name
player.location = :jail5
class Dungeon
    attr_accessor :player, :rooms, :prisoners, :gangsmen, :policemen
    @@counter = 0
    def initialize(player)
        @player = player
    end
end
my_dungeon = Dungeon.new(player)
if my_dungeon.player.location.to_s.scan(/\D+/) == "jail"
    puts "yes"
end
```

This code is supposed to print "yes" on the screen, but it doesn't. I changed the == sign to != and surprisingly it printed "yes" !
I thought may be I understood the regular expression wrong so I typed this code:

```
puts my_dungeon.player.location.to_s.scan(/\D+/)
```

It prints "jail" on the screen, which means I wasn't wrong, was I ?
Can anyone explain this please ?

Comment: `scan` returns an array. You can use `if my_dungeon.player.location.to_s[/\D+/] == "jail"`. Are you sure `\D+` is the right pattern for you? It matches one or more chars other than digits.

Comment: yes, I don't want the digits. I thought `scan` returns a string, but now that you said it returns an array it makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wiktor's comment says, arrays are always truthy, and `scan` always returns an array, even if there are no matches. Instead you can use any of the following methods:

```
str = "jail5"

if str[/\D+/] # => nil or the match contents
if str.match /\D+/ # => nil or MatchData object
if str =~ /\D+/ # => nil or index of the match
unless str.scan(/\D+/).empty?
if str.scan(/\D+/).length > 0
```

In general when you come across surprising behavior like this you should do a bit of [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) - check what the result value is using `print` or a breakpoint.

Comment: Should be `match(/\D+/)`

Comment: Many thanks. I will make sure to try that next time.